# Get the matching value using %in% operator

Tags: r

Let's assume two dataframes: A and B.

```
Dataframe: A              Dataframe: B
    ColA1    ColA2        ColB1      
  | Dog   |   Dog  |    | Lion |  
  | Lion  |   Lion |    | Cat  |  
  | Zebra |   NA   |    | Tiger|  
  | Bat   |   NA   |    | Dog  |
```

I want to assign to ColA2 the matching value from ColB1.

```
A$ColA2 <- ifelse((A$ColA1 %in% B$ColB1), "occurence" , NA)
```

How can I get the matching value (= "occurence") both from ColB1? Namely, the matching value of "Lion" is taken from ColB1.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with expected output.

Comment: `ifelse` and `%in%` are vectorized; they goes through the whole vector, first doing the first element, effectively asking "Is the first element of column `ColA1` in `A` also listed in `ColB1`?", "Is the first element of column `ColA1` in `A` also listed in `ColB1`?", and so on. So if the first element of `ColA1` is also in `ColB1`, which element is it? The first of course. In this case, `ifelse` would take the first element of the second argument. So this should work: 

`x <- ifelse(A$ColA1 %in% B$ColB1, A$ColA1 , NA)`

Comment: I edited my question. It's slightly different

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `match` function to obtain the values of A$Col1 that match with B$Col1. or directly use `%in%`.

```
 A$col1[match(A$col1,B$col1,nonmatch=0)]
 A$col1[A$col1%in%B$col1]
```

to find those for B$Col1, we interchange the positions:
      B$col1[B$col1%in%A$col1]